# ReactでAxiosを使用し結果を表示する仕組みで、mapのエラー(TS105)となる

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-jsx, axios

Reactを始めたばかりで質問がおかしければ申し訳ございません

単純にAxiosで取得した結果を画面に列挙するだけのを勉強しています
以下のコードです

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

const searchGoogleBooks = async (searchString: string) => {
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
  const params = { q: searchString };
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { params });
    return { isSuccess: true, data: response.data, error: null };
  } catch (error) {
    return { isSuccess: false, data: null, error };
  }
}

const Signin: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchResult, changeSearchResult] = useState<any>(null);

  const clickSignin = async () => {
    const result = await searchGoogleBooks('API');
    if (result.isSuccess) {
      changeSearchResult(result.data);
    } else {
      window.alert(String(result.error));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="button" value="Sign in" onClick={clickSignin} />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {
          searchResult !== null && ({
            searchResult.map((item: any) => {
              return (<li>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>);
            })
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signin;
```

後半の`searchResult.map((item: any) => {` `.map`の`.`のところで以下のエラーが出て解消出来ず質問させていただきました

```
',' が必要です。ts(1005)
```

出力している

```
        {
          searchResult !== null && ({
            searchResult.map((item: any) => {
              return (<li>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>);
            })
          })
        }
```

をコメントアウトすれば、APIの結果は取れているところまではは確認しています

mapの使い方が間違っているのかもしれませんが対応出来ずにいます
対応方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか

やっていることと、コンポーネントの名前`Signin`と整合性が取れていないのはご容赦ねがいます

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchResult.map`をラップしている`({})`が不要ですね。

`<ul></ul>`の中身を次のように置換すると良いでしょう。

```
{searchResult !== null && searchResult.map((item: any) => {
  return <li>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>;
})}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。ほかに悪いところもあったので、最終的なコードは別途記載します。mapあたりはネットのコードを流用していたのですが理解が出来ていませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

最終的には、

```
{searchResult !== null && searchResult.items.map((item: any) => {
  return (<li key={item.id}>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>);
})}
```

というように直しました。